# Backbone Fetch triggers success but returns zero length

Tags: backbone.js, fetch

I am new to Backbone. Pardon me if this has been answered before. I tried googling but couldn't reach a solution.

```
window.InfoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:InfoModel,
    url:"../api/info",
      parse: function (response) {
        console.log("In Parse" + response.length)
        return response;
    }
});
```

Here this returns the length correctly as 1

However it shows up as 0 here.

```
    this.InfoCollection.fetch({success:function(){console.log(this.length)}});
```

Consequently when I initiate a view with the InfoModel, it fails.

Can any expert please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> **parse** `collection.parse(response, options)`
>
> [...] The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection.

Apparently you're getting the expected array (of length one) in `response` but then your `parse` returns just the first element:

```
return response[0];
```

But the collection is expecting an *array of objects* (one object per model) not a *single object*. The result is that you end up with an empty collection because you didn't give it anything it could load; empty collections have a length of zero and that's what you're seeing.

You probably want your `parse` to look like this:

```
parse: function (response) {
    console.log("In Parse" + response.length)
    return response;
}
```

That's just the default `parse` implementation with a `console.log` call thrown in so you probably don't need it all.

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning it. However I did try it with response first. A Firebug showed me the children of Response so I tried to send only the first child

Comment: What does `response` look like?

Comment: It looks like a normal array object. response[0][infoId] , response[0][firstvar] , etc etc

Comment: What happens if you `return response` in your `parse` method?

Comment: The names of the collection object and the definition were clashing. 

I renamed it to 

    this.infoColl = new InfoCollection()

and it works.